# How to use Apache POI to get an signed docx infomation?

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml, digital-signature

I know when we unzip an docx file which is signed , the signature infomation is stored in *sig1.xml* in *_xmlsignatures* folder . Now I want to know how to get these information by Apache POI.

[image]

Comment: Maybe use google? [Some docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/poifs/crypt/dsig/SignatureInfo.html). [They even provide an example...](http://poi.apache.org/encryption.html#Validating+a+signed+office+document)

Comment: I have an unfinished POI patch, which might help you. The approach there is, to validate the signature and the certificate and other informations are written to the SignatureConfig object.

Comment: @kiwiwings,well,now I can get the x509Certificate . Could you tell me how to get the information about <mdssi:SignatureTime>?

Comment: I've added the patch via [#62452](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62452). Now you can set `SignatureConfig.setUpdateConfigOnValidate(true)` and read the signatureTime and a few other properties from the SignatureConfig instance. This will be available in POI 4.0.0